# Python interpretation of a possible functional programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, functional-programming

Hia all, I am reading a python script which has this syntax `a,b = foo(c,d)(f,g)` Since it is the first time I am seeing this syntax. I do not know how to interpret that. Can you Help me to understand plz. Thanks.

`Unfortunately I am not authorized to share the code.`

foo has a structure like the following.

```
def foo(n):
   def todo(func):
      def dodo(*args, **kargs):
         ...
         ...
         ...
         return func(*args, **kargs)
      return dodo
   return todo
```

Comment: The function `foo(c, d)` is probably returning another function that accepts two parameters.

Comment: and that function returns a 2-tuple, a 2-list or something that can be decomposed into `a,b` - but without the implementation of foo this is not really answerable nor is it in and of itself a good question for SO.

Comment: Some function (or other callable) is being returned (and possibly created by) the object named `foo` (itself a function or other type of callable). The latter is returning a sequence of some of length 2 whose element are being "unpacked" and assigned to the variables `a` & `b`.

Comment: @Patrick: I disagree. The OP seems to only be asking how to understand what the code shown should be interpreted as doing (generally or abstracty).

Answer (score 3):

Hia all, `a,b = foo(c,d)(f,g)` means

1. Execute foo with args c and d (returns a function) (`foo(c,d)`)
2. Execute the function returned with args f and g (returns a list with lenth 2) (`foo(c,d)(f,g)` (`func(f,g)`))
3. assign a the first item of the list (`a,b = foo(c,d)(f,g)` (`a = foo(c,d)(f,g)[0]`))
4. assign b the second item of the list (`b = foo(c,d)(f,g)[1]`)

so `a,b = foo(c,d)(f,g)` is a way to write

```
save = foo(c,d)(f,g)
a = save[0]
b = save[1]
```

Examples:

(warning: c,d,f and g as are ints in my Examples)

foo returns a function. Example:

```
def foo(c,d):
    if c+d > 10:
        return func1
    else:
        return func2
```

so you execute func1 (or func2) with f and g,

then you save output 1 to a and output2 to b

Example for func1 and func2:

```
def func1(f,g):
    return [f+1,g+1]
def func2(f,g):
    return [f-1,g-1]
```

then would the snippet would be used as following:

```
c = 5
d = 8
f = 19
g = 4
def func1(f,g):
    return [f+1,g+1]
def func2(f,g):
    return [f-1,g-1]

def foo(c,d):
    if c+d > 10:
        return func1
    else:
        return func2

a,b = foo(c,d)(f,g)
```

if we add prints to the end then

a will be 20

and b will be 5.